# Pivot_Longer with Multiple Variables

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

In a previous question ([Creating a New Variable for Each Unique Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70614002/creating-a-new-variable-for-each-unique-group)), I learned how to use the "pivot_longer()" function in R for formatting data:

```
v1 <- c("2010-2011","2011-2012", "2012-2013", "2013-2014", "2014-2015") 
v2 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")

data_1 = data.frame(var_1 = rnorm(871, 10,10), var_2 = rnorm(871, 5,5))

data_1$dates <- as.factor(sample(v1, 871, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)))

data_1$types <- as.factor(sample(v2, 871, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)))


data_2 = data.frame(var_1 = rnorm(412, 10,10), var_2 = rnorm(412, 5,5))

data_2$dates <- as.factor(sample(v1, 412, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)))

data_2$types <- as.factor(sample(v2, 412, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)))


data_3 = data.frame(var_1 = rnorm(332, 10,10), var_2 = rnorm(332, 5,5))

data_3$dates <- as.factor(sample(v1, 332, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)))

data_3$types <- as.factor(sample(v2, 332, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)))

data_1$group = as.factor("A")
 data_2$group = as.factor("B")
 data_3$group = as.factor("C")

#data frame 
 dt = rbind(data_1, data_2, data_3)

library(tidyverse)

list(data_1, data_2, data_3) %>% 
  set_names(paste0("data_", 1:length(.))) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "data_nr") %>% 
  count(data_nr, dates, name = "my_counts") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = dates, values_from = my_counts, names_prefix = "counts_")
```

This produces the following data set:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  data_nr `counts_2010-2011` `counts_2011-2012` `counts_2012-2013` `counts_2013-2014` `counts_2014-2015`
  <chr>                <int>              <int>              <int>              <int>              <int>
1 data_1                 443                171                 83                 93                 81
2 data_2                 200                 78                 44                 47                 43
3 data_3                 172                 61                 32                 33                 34
```

**I would like to add several more columns to the above table, such as:**

- `mean_var1_2010-2011`
- `mean_var1_2011-2012`
  etc.
- `mean_var2_2010-2011`
  `mean_var2_2011-2012`
  etc.
- `30thquantile_var1_2010-2011`
- `30thquantile_var1_2011-2012` etc.
- `30thquantile_var2_2010-2011`
- `30thquantile_var2_2011-2012` etc.

**I tried to modify the above code to do this:**

```
    #put everything in one data frame to make it easier
    data_1$group = as.factor("A")
 data_2$group = as.factor("B")
 data_3$group = as.factor("C")

#data frame 
 dt = rbind(data_1, data_2, data_3)

#QUESTION
  final = dt %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "data_nr") %>% 
  count(data_nr, dates, name = "my_counts") %>% 
  mean(data_nr, dates, var_1, name = "my_mean_var_1") %>% 
  mean(data_nr, dates, var_2, name = "my_mean_var_2") %>% 
  quantile(data_nr, dates, var_1, probs = 0.3, name = "my_30_percentile_var_1") %>% 
 quantile(data_nr, dates, var_2, probs = 0.3, name = "my_30_percentile_var_2") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = dates, values_from = c(my_counts, my_mean_var_1, my_mean_var_2, my_30_percentile_var_1, my_30_percentile_var_2), names_prefix = "counts_")
```

**But I don't think this is the correct way to do this**

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have a dataframe `dt` looking like this.

```
> head(dt)
       var_1      var_2     dates types group
1 27.5979494 -0.1823654 2014-2015     C     A
2  8.2266573  4.9165620 2011-2012     D     A
3 14.9731504  0.5343270 2010-2011     A     A
4 22.5124430  2.3846317 2010-2011     A     A
5  7.5399511 -5.1710378 2014-2015     A     A
6  0.1473477  5.2621775 2014-2015     A     A
```

Then your tasks can be done more efficiently using `summarize` together with `across`. You can do

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt %>%       #v-----------------------I changed this one from "data_nr" to "group"
  group_by(group, dates) %>% 
  summarize(
    counts = n(), 
    across(
      .cols = c(var_1, var_2), 
      .fns = list(mean = mean, `30thquantile` = ~quantile(., probs = 0.3)), 
      .names = "{.fn}_{.col}"
    ), 
    .groups = "drop"
  ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = dates, values_from = -c(group, dates))
                                                     #^------------... and this one as well
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 26
  group `counts_2010-201~ `counts_2011-20~ `counts_2012-20~ `counts_2013-20~ `counts_2014-20~ `mean_var_1_201~ `mean_var_1_201~
  <fct>             <int>            <int>            <int>            <int>            <int>            <dbl>            <dbl>
1 A                   412              193               84               85               97             9.88             9.75
2 B                   209               74               37               49               43            10.0             11.4 
3 C                   135               87               44               33               33            10.5              9.33
# ... with 18 more variables: mean_var_1_2012-2013 <dbl>, mean_var_1_2013-2014 <dbl>, mean_var_1_2014-2015 <dbl>,
#   30thquantile_var_1_2010-2011 <dbl>, 30thquantile_var_1_2011-2012 <dbl>, 30thquantile_var_1_2012-2013 <dbl>,
#   30thquantile_var_1_2013-2014 <dbl>, 30thquantile_var_1_2014-2015 <dbl>, mean_var_2_2010-2011 <dbl>,
#   mean_var_2_2011-2012 <dbl>, mean_var_2_2012-2013 <dbl>, mean_var_2_2013-2014 <dbl>, mean_var_2_2014-2015 <dbl>,
#   30thquantile_var_2_2010-2011 <dbl>, 30thquantile_var_2_2011-2012 <dbl>, 30thquantile_var_2_2012-2013 <dbl>,
#   30thquantile_var_2_2013-2014 <dbl>, 30thquantile_var_2_2014-2015 <dbl>
```

Comment: @ ekoam : Thank you so much for your answer! Suppose I have the following frame

Comment: data_1$group = as.factor("A");  data_2$group = as.factor("B"); data_3$group = as.factor("C");  dt = rbind(data_1, data_2, data_3)

Comment: Can you please show me how "dt" can be used to create the answer you have given? Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry @Noob, I don't understand your follow-up question. The `dt` in your comment seems to be different from `my_data` given in your post above. Can you explain more about what is your new requirement now?

Comment: @  ekoam: hello! I made an edit to the question - can you please look where it says "QUESTION"? Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @Noob, I have updated the code. I hope that this clarifies the change that you need to do for the code.